# Match curly brace with new line

Tags: sed, gnu

Trying to match a string + line break + left curly brace using `sed`.

```
sub feature_get_web_php_mode
{
my ($d) = @_;
my $server = &find_domain_server($d);
```

to become this

```
sub feature_get_web_php_mode
{
return 'fcgid';
my ($d) = @_;
my $server = &find_domain_server($d);
```

My expression regex looks like this:`s|sub feature_get_web_php_mode\n{|CHANGE_CODE|` but it doesn't work.

Tried to find the reason why open curly brace doesn't match at the beginning but no clues.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sed` read single lines at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tried to find the reason why open curly brace doesn't match at beginning but no clues.

By default, `sed` operates on one line at a time, therefore the lines you read cannot have `\n` inside of them. Since you are using GNU `sed`, if offers the `-z` option which allows you to operate on blocs of text separated with NUL (`\0`) characters. The only thing you have to change to your command is to add that `-z` option:

```
sed -z "s|sub feature_get_web_php_mode\n{\n|&return 'fcgid';\n|"
```

Just beware that I expect no NUL character to be present in your input file (it looks like a regular text file) so it will be loaded entirely in memory so that `sed` can process it (which is probably harmless since this is a program file).

If your file is really too big, you can try this alternate version:

```
sed "/^sub feature_get_web_php_mode\$/ { N; s|\n{|&\nreturn 'fcgid';|; }"
```

For the record, the version below is strictly conforming to Posix:

```
sed "/^sub feature_get_web_php_mode\$/ { N; s|\n{|&\\
return 'fcgid';|; }"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Updated my question to be more clear. I must match these two lines because are the unique string in a very long long file.

Comment: @SilverStoreS It's a very long file but it's a program file, right? By today's standard, I expect it to be much smaller than your machine's RAM, so you can use `sed -z`. Else, if your file is 100MB long and you are limited in memory, try the Posix version.

Comment: Hi @xhienne. Thank you very much. Posix worked for me. Was struggling with this at 6h. Life saver.

Comment: POSIX `sed` can't insert a newline with `\n` in the replacement part of the `s///` command.  Also, for POSIX `sed`, you need a `;` before that final `}`.

Comment: https://sed.js.org/?gist=df49b71f1de4c5de34c47e49955d1739

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, answer updated.

Comment: @SilverStoreS From the standard: "The `}` shall be preceded by a newline or `;` (before any optional blank characters preceding the `}`). "  A newline can be substituted into a line with `s///` if using a _literal_ newline. Also: "The meaning of an unescaped backslash immediately followed by any character other than `&`, backslash, a digit, newline, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified". https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html  What GNU `sed` does with `--posix` is definitely not related to these things.

Comment: @SilverStoreS As stated by Kusalananda, using `\n` in the substitution string does indeed make my program not Posix compliant BUT the fact that GNU `sed --posix` understands `\n` in the substitution string does not make GNU sed non-compliant. Posix just says it is unspecified, it doesn't say that `\n` must not be interpreted as a newline (what GNU sed does). All this just means that you just cannot use `sed --posix` to validate a Posix sed program.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for the clarifications and for sharing with details. My bash skills are enough to make things work but sometimes we need a master :) approach.

Comment: @SilverStoreS I _believe_ that what the `--posix` option to GNU `sed` does is to make a few of the editing commands behave as POSIX describes rather than as GNU has changed them. I think it usually matters in edge cases, but I don't really use GNU `sed` that often so I don't really know.

Comment: The usual wisdom to add a newline in older seds is to embrace the fact that the hold space contains a plain newline. So, a simple G should add a newline. `sed "/^${start}/ { N; /\n{$/{ G; s/$/${rpla}/ } }"`.

Comment: (you need to divide each command into separate -e sections) ... or to write them on separate lines, which is more readable, and which I usually do but I wanted to stay close to the command in the question because, all in all, it wasn't that bad. Thanks @Isaac for your insightful suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To change the text

```
sub feature_get_web_php_mode
{
my ($d) = @_;
my $server = &find_domain_server($d);
```

into

```
sub feature_get_web_php_mode
{
return 'fcgid';
my ($d) = @_;
my $server = &find_domain_server($d);
```

by means of matching the string `sub feature_get_web_php_mode` followed on the next line by `{`, and then inserting the new line

```
return 'fcgid';
```

you would have to do

```bsh
sed '/^sub feature_get_web_php_mode$/ { N; /\n{$/ a\
'"return 'fcgid'"';
}' file
```

This locates the line that is exactly `sub feature_get_web_php_mode`.  Once this is found, the next line is appended to the input buffer with a newline character in-between, using the `N` command.  Next, if the pattern `\n{$` matches, then the line that was read in with `N` is the single character `{`, and the new line can be added.

The new line is added with the `a` command.  The `a` command looks like

```
a\
text to be added
```

Since the text that we want to add contains single quotes, and because our `sed` script is quoted with single quotes, we temporarily break out of the `sed` program's single quotes to add the text in double quotes.

Alternatively, double-quote the whole expression (remember to escape the `\` after `a` here):

```bsh
sed "/^sub feature_get_web_php_mode$/ { N; /\n{$/ a\\
return 'fcgid';
}" file
```

Using GNU `sed`, you can get away with doing it like so:

```bsh
sed -e '/^sub feature_get_web_php_mode$/ { N; /\n{$/ a \' -e "return 'fcgid';" -e '}' file
```

Other `sed` implementations would possibly be able to run this too, but might not insert a newline after the added line.

---

Another way to do this is to prepare a patch file:

```
diff -u file.old file.new >file.patch
```

This may result in a patch file looking like

```
--- file.old    Wed May 12 22:44:00 2021
+++ file.new    Wed May 12 22:44:15 2021
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 sub feature_get_web_php_mode
 {
+return 'fcgid';
 my ($d) = @_;
 my $server = &find_domain_server($d);
```

To apply this to some file, creating a new file with the change incorporated:

```bsh
patch -o somefile.patched somefile <file.patch
```

Without `-o somefile.patch`, the changes are applied directly to `somefile` and the original is backed up as `somefile.orig`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to edit the definition of a `subroutine` in your `perl` code.

FYI, `Perl`, subroutines can be defined/redefined just like variables.

To do that, put these three steps in your code to effect the change you are desiring:

```
{
  no warnings q(redefine);
  undef &feature_get_php_mode;
  *feature_get_php_mode = sub { return q(fcgid); };
}
```

---

But if you must edit your code then you could do as follows:

```
sed -e '
  /^sub feature_get_web_php_mode$/!b
  n;/^{$/G
  s/\n/&return q(fcgid);/
' file
```

Notes:-

- I have used the Perlish way to use single quoted strings via the `q()` operator. This saves blushes on tripping up in our quoting tasks.